# How to get all methods for a type

Tags: julia

I have a type `T`, how can I get all methods that are specialized to this type in the REPL? My motivation is that `T` is defined in a package and it may not be easy to see *what I am meant to do with `T`* from the source code.

In summary, I'd want something like

```
functions(T)
```

as `methods` already exists but it requires the functions I want to find out about

Comment: Could anyone please specify the syntax to list all methods available in the "Example" module or any module which is installed from external source with Pkg.add("module_name")?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to use `methodswith(T)`:

```
help?> methodswith
search: methodswith

  methodswith(typ[, module or function][, showparents])

  Return an array of methods with an argument of type typ. If optional showparents
  is true, also return arguments with a parent type of typ, excluding type Any.

  The optional second argument restricts the search to a particular module or
  function.

julia> type Foo end

julia> methodswith(Foo)
0-element Array{Method,1}

julia> foo(::Foo) = nothing
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methodswith(Foo)
1-element Array{Method,1}:
 foo(::Foo) at none:1
```